# UITableView.visibleCells.contains(JDHeaderTableViewCell()) always return false

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I print visible cells then it shows two type of cells, see below`po cells
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <David.JDHeaderTableViewCell: 0x7fc6880e7a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 375 210); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000600200>>
  ▿ 1 : <David.JDContainerTableViewCell: 0x7fc68a810000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 250; 375 792); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000655540>>`

But When I try to get the cell object it returns false

```
(lldb) po cells.contains(JDHeaderTableViewCell())
```

false

I Have tried with below lines:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = self.jdTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! JDHeaderTableViewCell
```

But I need to check first and then needed particular cell.

Comment: because of `JDHeaderTableViewCell()` will create a new instance of JDHeaderTableViewCell

Comment: Yes it does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains` method is used for checking object is contained in given array or not, here you are creating new object as `JDHeaderTableViewCell()` and checking if it is contained in given visible cells or not. As you have created new empty object, it is obvious that it will return false.

If you want to get `JDHeaderTableViewCell` typed cell from visible cells and use that one then do following:

```
let headersCells = tableView.visibleCells?.filter({ (cell) -> Bool in
                return cell is JDHeaderTableViewCell
            })
```

the `headerCells` will be nil if `visibleCells` will not have `JDHeaderTableViewCell`. If it contains the array will contain all that objects. Now you have to just get whichever index you want.

Comment: actually just `cells.contains(where: { $0 is JDHeaderTableViewCell } )`, or even `cells.contains { $0 is JDHeaderTableViewCell }` would do the trick